# Different multiplicity between derived classes that inherits the same base class

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, diagram

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27uj6.png]

Having 4 classes (A, B, C and D)
Knowing that classes B & C inherits class A, is it a design flaw to have a different multiplicity from class D to class B and class D to class C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is definitely not a design flaw. The cardinality of the associations between B/D and between C/D are properties of the specializations B and C only. The base class A is not affected by these associations.

An example could be a course (D) which has at most one teacher (B) and several students (C) which both are persons (A).